# C# how to know if removable disk is a usb drive, or a sd card?

Tags: c#, removable

Windows 7 platform, C#

I use the following statement to list all drives:

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

then I can use DriveType to find out all those removable disks:

```
foreach (var drive in drives)
{
     if(drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
         yield return drive;
}
```

now my problem is, SD-card disk and USB flashdisk shared same driveType: Removable, so how can i only find USB flashdisk out?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of `ManagementObjectSearcher` using it to query the disk drives that are USB, then obtain the corresponding unit letter and return only the `DriveInfo` of which `RootDirectory.Name` is contained in the result set.

**Using LINQ Query Expressions:**

```
static IEnumerable<DriveInfo> GetUsbDevices()
{
    IEnumerable<string> usbDrivesLetters = from drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()
                                           from o in drive.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition").Cast<ManagementObject>()
                                           from i in o.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk").Cast<ManagementObject>()
                                           select string.Format("{0}\\", i["Name"]);

    return from drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
           where drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && usbDrivesLetters.Contains(drive.RootDirectory.Name)
           select drive;
}
```

**Using LINQ Extension Methods:**

```
static IEnumerable<DriveInfo> GetUsbDevices()
{
    IEnumerable<string> usbDrivesLetters = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()
        .SelectMany(drive => drive.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition").Cast<ManagementObject>())
        .SelectMany(o => o.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk").Cast<ManagementObject>())
        .Select(i => Convert.ToString(i["Name"]) + "\\");

    return DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(drive => drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && usbDrivesLetters.Contains(drive.RootDirectory.Name));
}
```

**Using foreach:**

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetUsbDrivesLetters()
{                
    foreach (ManagementObject drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'").Get())
        foreach (ManagementObject o in drive.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition"))
            foreach (ManagementObject i in o.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk"))
                yield return string.Format("{0}\\", i["Name"]);
}

static IEnumerable<DriveInfo> GetUsbDevices()
{
    IEnumerable<string> usbDrivesLetters = GetUsbDrivesLetters();
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && usbDrivesLetters.Contains(drive.RootDirectory.Name))
            yield return drive;
}
```

To use `ManagementObject` you need to add reference to `System.Management`

I haven't tested it well because now I don't have any SD card, but I hope it helps

Comment: hi @codroipo, usbDrivesLetters returns all removable drives, including the sd-card. But i love ManagementObjectSearcher it looks much more professional lol, so would you please help a more little how to filt out only the usb drive?

Comment: @OhMyDog In Device manager, under which node is shown your SD Card Reader?

Comment: @OhMyDog Can you also tell me what is the output of `new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(f => (string)f["PNPDeviceID"]).ToList()`?

Comment: problem solved. I check pnpDeviceID and found difference between USB-flash and SD-card, thank you codroipo!

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to be correct, after you know how to do it now? Thx

Comment: In windows 10 the Win32_DiskDrive InterfaceType='USB' is not returning all USB drives (they return InterfaceType='SCSI').
I think it has to do with type-c USB drives. )-:

Answer (score 1):

I had to check for USB-Devices in an older project and solved it like this:

```
 Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE deviceInterface;
 deviceInterface = (Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)
 string name = new string(deviceInterface.dbcc_name);
 Guid g = new Guid(deviceInterface.dbcc_classguid);
 if (g.ToString() == "a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed")
 {*DO SOMETHING*}
```

I get the GUID and check if the devices GUID is the USB-GUID.

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I think the OP doesn't have the GUID

Comment: also thank you npit, but i focused on codroipo's answer, sorry for not trying yours.